# Is the $\nu_e$ massive?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

[Neutrino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino#Mass) oscillations imply that the $\nu_\tau$ is more massive than the $\nu_\mu$, and the $\nu_\mu$ is more massive than the $\nu_e$, so it's inferred that the $\nu_\mu$ and $\nu_\tau$ have mass. But is there any direct evidence that the $\nu_e$ is massive? I think we'd all be surprised at this point if it wasn't, but has anyone managed a measurement or to place a *lower* limit on the mass yet?

Comment: As far as I remember, the lower limits on its mass are all negative.

Comment: The flavour and mass eigenstates of neutrinos aren't aligned (by convention), so you can't talk about the mass of each neutrino flavour.

The mass eigenstates are labelled $\nu_1$, $\nu_2$ and $\nu_3$. There are measurements of the absolute difference in masses between the mass eigenstates (e.g. $\Delta m^2_{12}$), but their order is unknown.

Comment: Also by convention the mass state 1 is the one with the largest electron flavor admixture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The $\nu_e$ is a mixture of three mass eigenstates $\nu_1,\nu_2,\nu_3$, at least two of which are massive.  The mixing coefficients form the [PMNS matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontecorvo%E2%80%93Maki%E2%80%93Nakagawa%E2%80%93Sakata_matrix).

For neutrinos, mass and flavor are not simultaneous observables, so the $\nu_e$ does not have a well-defined mass of its own.

Comment: Ah, that answers that. I take it the jury is still out on whether the third mass eigenstate is massive then?

Comment: @Kyle My impression is that most people assume that it is, but we can't show that from data until we know the absolute masses or can show that the sum is large enough.